# How to give someone a c/c++ programme without giving them the source

Tags: c++, software-distribution

I want to give a C++ programme to someone for testing but I don't want them to see the source just yet. My main issues are that I don't know what platform that person is using and I don't want to create a shared library unless I have no other option. Ideally, I would like to send headers and object files for the person to compile and link him/herself but as far as I know that would only work if the person has the same set up that I have.

I am currently using Windows but I'm comfortable working on any Unix-like system as well and I am not using an IDE, in case you need that information

Comment: You'd need to give them that lib or dll if you're not going to let them see the source.

Comment: Hmmm, wanted to avoid this but OK. Thanks

Comment: Ask the other party what platform they have.  Then give them a binary that'll run on that platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a Windows development environment allows you to bind some native always backward compatible [winapi](/questions/tagged/winapi) functions. The distribution of correctly setup binary `.dll` files, along with consistent headers, is enough.

For Linux distributions, the scenario is different, since you need to have a distributed package compiled from source (that's disclosed), or distributed binaries for every Linux distributions you actually want to support.

---

If you want to avoid source code disclosure, where it's needed to compile on specific target systems, use a licencing mechanism that's preventing to run it.

Comment: I see, but I'm not using winapi in the programme. Just standard library stuff.

Comment: @Lelo305: Which in turn will use the OS DLL's. Furthermore, your .obj would depend on the _exact_ Standard Library version in MSVC (aka MSVCRT)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the choice of machine is "reasonable" - in other words, it's something running Linux, Windows, Android or MacOS and a reasonable target processor such as MIPS, Sparc, x86 or ARM, then one POSSIBLE solution is to use `clang -S -emit-llvm yourfile.cpp` to produce an intermediate form of the LLVM "virtual machine code". This can then, using `llc`, be compiled to machine code for any target that LLVM supports.

It's not completely impossible to figure out roughly what the source code looked like, but unless someone wants to put a LOT of effort into running your code, they won't be able to see what the code does. And even giving someone a binary allows them, if they are that way inclined, to reverse engineer the code.

The other alternative, as I see it, is that you demonstrate the code on your machine [or a machine under your control].

There are also tools that can "obfuscate" source-code (rename variables, structure/class members and functions to `a`, `b`, `c`; remove any comments; and "unformat" the code - all of which makes it much harder to understand what the code does). Sorry, you'll have to google to find a good one, as I have never used such a thing myself. And again, of course, it's not IMPOSSIBLE to recover the code into something that can be used and modified and rebuilt. There is really no way to avoid giving the customer something they can compile unless you know what OS/processor it is for.

Comment: Isn't it true that `.ll` files can be easily decompiled?

Comment: Depends, it's not exactly C source code, and if you run the (no longer maintained) `C backend` to "regenerate C", you get the same sort of junky code that you get from some "machine code to C" reverse engineering tools - yes, you can recompile the code, but it's pretty much obfuscated. You can't for example tell the difference between for-loops, do-while loops and while-loops, switch and if-else will be "equalized". But it's true that data structures are often still visible in LLVM IR. But it's certianly not like giving the original source code. All depends on the level of paranoia...